# How can I change the color of the open tab in Firefox?

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox

The newest version just indicates which tab is open with a little "x" - which, for me, is difficult to see when I have lots of tabs open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Tab Mix Plus addon, and in `Tools`, `Tab Mix Plus Options`, click `Display`, click `Tab` and check the box that says `Current tab`. Now click `Customize Styles` and under `Current Tab` select how you want the current tab to be displayed (e.g. background colour of Red). Click `OK` and `OK` again.